# Easy eye tracking algorithm

Tags: human-computer-interface, human-interface

I'm looking for an algorithm that can tell me where are the eye(s) looking at on a photo/webcam realtime feed.

I've already searched a lot but I don't want to start with a lot of complexity right now.

It's just for fun. My idea it's to have some method that receives an image and returns a coordinate with the place that the user is looking (on the computer screen).

Comment: Since you've already searched a lot you've surely encountered many solutions for this. You probably also know that since computer vision is a complex and difficult topic you will necessarily meet with a certain amount of complexity. Can you be more specific, then, about how the information you've already found hasn't met your needs?

Comment: Since most eyetracking is a black box, IP its hard to develop your own without your own data set. That being said I have seen some developments around eyetracking AI program that are getting more and more robust over time. This might help in your journey, written by our in house neuroscientist: https://imotions.com/blog/10-terms-metrics-eye-tracking/ https://imotions.com/blog/screen-based-eye-tracking-module/